# Python : generate a graph for a social network

Tags: python, social-networking

I have installed matplotlib and networkx packages.
Can someone tell me the function present in these packages that can be used to generate a social network graph like graph for film actor collaborations, co-authorship or even a graph for a P2P network.

Comment: I found this function that draws a social network graph for 10 actors.
But I need a bigger graph
http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.krackhardt_kite_graph.html#networkx.krackhardt_kite_graph

Answer (score 3):

I think that matplotlib is not too suitable for this task. Try [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) instead.

Also, [this post](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=203) shows how Christian S. Perone used [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) to create 3D visualization of Twitter users

Answer (score 2):

I would use [PyDot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/), it's the pythton binding of the graphviz library.

Answer (score 1):

Count this as a second vote for [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  The format is pretty simple, and the layout engine is powerful.  Having installed Graphviz, you could then add PyDot to run things, or simply write your data to files with format showing the graph structure.

Look at the Graphviz user's manual ([pdf](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)).

If you wanted to roll your own, matplotlib would be my choice, but layout is complicated.

Comment: If you feel the need to downvote, it would help to explain why.  Do you think this is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de) since it has an interface to graphviz, which is very easy to use. See the documentation in the website for more details.